# Node.js & mongoDB: uncaughtException: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, require

I have this import

```
const User = require("./Usermodel")'
```

and I want to change it to

```
const User = require("./UserModel")
```

When I try to change the import-spelling, to be consistant with my other imports and the actual module-name I'm importing. I keep getting the error:

```
uncaughtException: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
```

What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the same import in different files. The spelling must be the same in each of them.